# RxJS Таймер циклических запросов учитывающий время ответа

Tags: typescript, angular, angular5, rxjs

Ищу метод в RxJS (v6.x) что бы отправлять циклические запросы на сервер, предположим каждые 30 скунд на подобии `{ timer } from 'rxjs'`, но проблема в том что-бы не учитывать время самого запроса. На пример если бэк отвечает 10 секунд то интервал между запросами будет 30 установленные в настройках таймера + 10 ожижание ответа.

Возможно есть в RxJS классы которые как раз для этого хорошо подойдут для такой задачи? Вызов будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
export class UserService {
    constructor(private readonly api: ApiService) {}

    public readonly user$ = new ReplaySubject<IUser>(1);

    ...

    private load(): void {
        this.api.getUser() // getUser(): Observable<IUser>
            .subscribe(user => this.user$.next(user));
    }
}
```

Вот для такого кеса нужно организовать таймер вызовов с описанным выще поведением, возможно в RxJS есть что-то подходящее что бы не костылить?

Тоесть отсчет следующих 30 сек должен начинаться только после получения ответа от бэка каким бы он не был.

(p. s. Не спрашивайте почему в таком месте не web socket используются сочинял не я)

Comment: я немного не понял твою задачу, нужно делать запросы каждые 30 секунд , при этом если бек отвечает через 20 секунд, то следующий запрос сделать через 50 секунд, ПОСЛЕ ТОГО как придет ответ на предыдущий запрос?

Comment: @overthesanity да верно. Так что бы не заспамить сервер если он начнет тормозить тоесть отсчет следующих 30 сек должен начинаться только после получения ответа.

Comment: а если сервер вернул 40*/50* (code)?

Comment: @overthesanity пока не уточнял эти требования, но подразумевается что реакцию на resolve и reject можно будет задать. В проекте есть общая система обработки ошибок вероятно использоваться будет она и дальнейшие запросы посылать будет не нужно, в этом смысле понимать как остановить цикл тоже важно. Я сейчас в целом подход ищу к задаче а конкретную реализацию и обработчики то я напишу, сейчас именно правильный Rx оператор подобрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нетривиальная у тебя задача, но все же :)

Тут важен еще таков момент - если у тебя задан интервал в 10 секунд, то что делать если сервер не отвечает 10 секунд? Есть несколько вариантов, для чего и нужны все операторы, которые маппят на внутреннюю проекцию `switch|merge|concat|exhaustMap`. Важно понимать поставленную задачу и из требований исходить, что ты будешь использовать. Взглянем на такой пример:

```js
interval(300).pipe(
  switchMap(() => timer(400))
).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Меня никогда не увидят...');
});
```

`interval` будет генерировать события каждые 300 мс, `switchMap` подписывается на `interval` и проекцию `() => timer(400)`, при этом он подписывается на `interval` только 1 раз, а на проекцию каждый раз, как `interval` генерирует событие, в итоге получается бесконечный цикл, он не может дождаться генерации события от `timer(400)`, так как `interval(300)` генерирует событие быстрее.

`mergeMap` будет создавать параллельные подписки, `concatMap` создает очередь, `exhaustMap` игнорирует источник (`interval(300)`), пока `timer(400)` не сгенерирует событие.

В твоем случае тебе нужно исходить из требований к задаче, ты ее знаешь лучше меня, но давай взглянем на примеры:

```
interval(3000).pipe(
  concatMap(() => this.api.getUser())
).subscribe(user => {
  this.user$.next(user);
});
```

Не будем брать число 30. Я взял 3 секунды для интервала, если `() => this.api.getUser()` сгенерирует событие (вернет респонс) позднее, чем `interval(3000)` сгенерирует новое событие, то `concatMap` добавит новую проекцию в очередь. Если этого не нужно делать, то используй `exhaustMap`, он будет игнорировать `interval`, пока `getUser()` не ответит.

P.S. тебе нужен обычный `BehaviorSubject`, вместо `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: `что делать если сервер не отвечает 10 секунд?` не я наверно не удачно выразился. Мы ждем какого угодно ответа пока он не придет и только после того как сервер ответил мы либо оправляем новый запрос если ответ был 200, либо если ошибка то просто ее обрабатываем и больше запросов не шлем.

Comment: про `exhaustMap` это интересно а как его применить к последней конструкции?

Comment: также как и `concatMap` :)